# Detecting QR code using zxing

Tags: c#, zxing

I'm working on detecting the qrcode. My requirement is when the user show’s his/her QR code to the camera, the program has to detect and draw one box around the QR code. I’m using zxing library + C#. I searched many things but I’m not able to find any samples in this. Kindly anyone help me in this.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339612/zxing-sample-code-to-detect-qrcode-in-an-image.

Comment: If I read you well, you first want to detect *that* a QR code is in view and later (triggered by some user action?) read *what* is in there?

Comment: yes GertArnold that is what i want.

Comment: @user1081305: detecting the presence of a QR code must be possible with zxing, because that's what it does internally. I never did it. Look into the source if there is any public method that you can use.

Comment: i saw there is a seperate class called detector is avilable in side the Zxing. but they are giving bitmatrix as a input to the detector and i'm not able to convert the bitmap image into bitmatrix in c#.(i think it is avilable in java,i'm not sure).if u know how kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the detector class for this. The detector constructor takes a BitMatrix object as its sole argument which can be obtained from the BlackMatrix property of the BinaryBitmap object...

```
public string Detect(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        try
        {
            com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            BitMatrix bm = binBitmap.BlackMatrix;
            Detector detector = new Detector(bm);
            DetectorResult result = detector.detect();

            string retStr = "Found at points ";
            foreach (ResultPoint point in result.Points)
            {
                retStr += point.ToString() + ", ";
            }

            return retStr;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Failed to detect QR code.";
        }
    }
```